# Populating a co-occurrence matrix

Tags: r, matlab

I am looking for a fast and efficient way to populate a co-occurrence matrix(so as to say). 
Here is a sample of the data I am working with:

```
col1 col2
a e    
a f    
a e    
b f    
c g    
a e    
d f    
a e    
a g    
b e    
c e
```

And I want a matrix of the following form:

```
... e...  f...  g    
a    
b    
c    
d
```

with the corresponding entry relating to the frequency.

For example, element (3,1) in the matrix would correspond to frequency of the co-occurrence of (c,e) and should have a value of 1 and that of (1,1) should have a value 3 corresponding to 3 entries of (a,e) in the dataset.

I am currently individually calculating the items using two for loops and it takes an extremely long time to compute the matrix (the actual data has about a million rows).

Comment: sparse matrixes can give you a clue, especially they conversion to non-sparse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) to do exactly what you need:

```
spA = sparse(data(:,1), data(:,2), 1);
```

where `data` is your data, but as numbers. So you first have to convert alphabetic characters to doubles.

Sparse assembles row/column pairs from `data(:,1)` and `data(:,2)` adding 1 for every occurance of a pair. Note however that if you expect the matrix to be symmetric, you might need to sum `spA` and its transpose, depending on your data.

Comment: +1: Genius. Small comment though: `sparse` converts the datatype automagically; no need for manual conversion.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis it does indeed. But since `a` is 97, the sparse matrix will have empty beginning and only really start at row/column 97.

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution in R with `table`:

```
df <- read.table(text="col1 col2
a e    
a f    
a e    
b f    
c g    
a e    
d f    
a e    
a g    
b e    
c e", header = TRUE)

table(df)

    col2
col1 e f g
   a 4 1 1
   b 1 1 0
   c 1 0 1
   d 0 1 0
```